# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException: invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to create an activity where I can update a user profile but It keep telling me that the firstname variable is a null object reference, Can anyone help me please?

```
public class UpdateUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText lastname;
    private EditText firstname;
    private EditText phone;
    private Button btn_ajouter;
    private Button btn_quitter;
    Bundle b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        firstname=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.firstN1);
        lastname=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.lastN);
        phone= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.phonec);
        btn_ajouter= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_ap);
        btn_quitter= (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_lea);
        Intent i=this.getIntent();
        b=i.getExtras();
        String a=b.getString("first");
        String c=b.getString("last");
        String d=b.getString("phon");
        firstname.setText(firstname.getText().toString()+" "+a);
        lastname.setText(lastname.getText().toString()+" "+c);
        phone.setText(phone.getText().toString()+" "+d);
        btn_ajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Register.data.set(b.getInt("indice"),new           Contact(firstname.getText().toString(),lastname.getText().toString(),phone.getText().toString()));
                Register.sauvgarger();
                Intent i=new Intent(UpdateUser.this,Display.class);
                startActivity(i);
                try {
                    finish();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btn_quitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    finish();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my xml part

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstN1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstN1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phonec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastN"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"

        android:text="Update"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phonec" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Leave"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_ap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my Error log

1-28 02:39:52.076 9276-9276/com.example.tcyc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.tcyc, PID: 9276 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tcyc/com.example.tcyc.UpdateUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference at com.example.tcyc.UpdateUser.onCreate(UpdateUser.java:34) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Can you post your xml file `activity_add`?

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 1):

Check your activity_add xml,
Problem may be

```java
firstname=(EditText) this.findViewById(*R.id.firstN1*);
```

are the EditText id **is** **firstN1??**

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);` This is the layout you are trying to use. So make sure it has all the fields you want to access in `UpdateUser` activity. Because, actually, it seems like the layout was meant for an activity called `Add`.